# Spring Cloud Stream - Actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to expose Spring Boot actuator endpoint for my binding configuration. My app is quite simple just with couple of KStream bindings. It is written in functional way without any "binding" annotations like `@EnableBinding` or `@StreamListener`.
It is up and running and when I access **/actuator/bindings** it crashes with following exception: `` Binding implementation `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinding` must implement this operation before it is called (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinding["input"]) ``

My question is what the reason to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binding#isInput()` method and don't override it in DefaultBinding which is used for KStream? Or maybe `DefaultBinding` is completely wrong bean for KStream binding?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a small sample with your setup? That way we can troubleshoot it quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @sobychacko. Here is an example: https://github.com/VladimirYushkevich/spring-cloud-actuator-issue

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in response. This exception is thrown because Kafka Streams binder currently does not expose those bindings endpoints for applications to control. What exactly is your use case? Here is an issue that might be related. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/641. If you need this as a feature, please feel free to open an issue on GH and we can have further discussions there.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I am still facing this one and above github issue has been closed because of no activity.
On accessing /actuator/bindings I am still getting the same error. I need to pause,resume Kafka binders if target is down and saw in spring docs taht this can be easily acheived with actuator endpoints. Using below version:
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version> with Spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE
@sobychacko